# sqlite3 prepared statement fails if fk is null. It should not

Tags: ios, sqlite, foreign-keys

I use Sqlite3 in my iOS app.
If I try to run the command from the console:

```
 INSERT INTO documents (name,fk_1) VALUES ('pluto','')
```

everything is fine.
But when doing it  via prepared statement, the same fails:

```
INSERT INTO documents (name,fk_1) VALUES (?,?)
```

saying "foreign key constraint failed".The value of fk_1 = ''.

The table documents is

```
CREATE TABLE "documents" ("id" integer   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,"name" varchar,"attivita_id" integer NULL REFERENCES attivita(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I was supposing that I can use `NULL` value as FK, and I can, indeed, because from the command line (first query) it works. The same is not possible with prepared statements?
The code to execute a write is:

```
-(NSInteger)writeData:(NSDictionary* )data table:(NSString* )table
{
    sqlite3_stmt    *sqlStatement;
    NSMutableArray  *columns   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray  *values    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:data];
    @try {
        assert([data count] != 0);
        if ([[data allKeys] count] == 0) return 1;
        // Names/Values for INSERT
        //  id is AUTOINCREMENT
        [temp removeObjectForKey:@"id"];
        [columns addObjectsFromArray:[temp allKeys]];
        NSString        *cols      = [columns componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSMutableString *colNames  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:
                                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %s (",[table UTF8String]]];

        [colNames appendString:cols];
        [colNames appendString:@")"];

        // Values for INSERT
        [values addObjectsFromArray:[temp allValues] ];

        // Prepare the ? marks for bindings
        NSMutableArray * marks = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i=0 ; i < [values count]; i++)
             [marks addObject:@"?"];

        NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        NSMutableString *valNames   = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@" VALUES ("];
        [valNames appendString:[marks componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
        [valNames appendString:@")"];
        [colNames appendString:valNames];
        const char *sql = [colNames UTF8String];
#ifdef DEBUG
        // NSLog(@"avvDB writeDATA insert string %@",colNames);
#endif

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"DB:Problem with prepare statement write %s, data: %@",sqlite3_errmsg(db),data);
            NSLog(@"DB:Query %@",colNames);
            return 0;

        }
        // binding

    for(int i = 0; i < [values count]; i++)
    {
    // According to the doc, if the 3rd value is a null pointer, the effect is similar to 
   // sqlite3_bind_null
          if ([[values objectAtIndex:i] length] == 0 || [values objectAtIndex:i] == nil)
            sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, i+1, nil,-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        else
        {
            [s setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[values objectAtIndex:i]]];

            const char* currentValue = [s UTF8String];

            sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, i+1, currentValue,-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }

    }
    if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
       // NSLog(@"Location  inserted on database");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"DB:Error on write: %i %s %@",sqlite3_errcode(db),sqlite3_errmsg(db),data);
        NSLog(@"DB:Query %@",colNames);
    }
   // if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
   // {
   //     NSLog(@"Last id %llu %s",sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db),sqlite3_errmsg(db));
   //  }
//    NSLog(@"Ecexecuted  write %@",colNames);
    valNames = nil;
    colNames = nil;
    marks    = nil;
    s        = nil;


}// end try
@catch(NSException* e)
{
    NSLog(@"Eccezione in write %@",[e reason]);
}
@finally {

    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
    sqlStatement = nil;
    return sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
}
```

}

Comment: How do you pass null value? because you should use the [NSNull null] object for your parameter instead of nil or NULL

Comment: Using a parameter for one column should not change the handling of another column. Are you really sure that this is the exact query you're using? Please show the entire code for the prepared statement.

Comment: I added the complete code of the write with prepared statment.

Comment: @Luca I added NSNull but noting change (an empty string behaves as nil from the DB point of view.

Comment: I found a solution I do not like: if the FK is constrained, when it is NULL it MUST not be in the query. But this is very difficult to handle, especially for data received remotely.

Comment: It seems that the problem is ONLY with the prepare statement. In all other case (from console for example) id admits NULL values for the FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty string is **not** the same as NULL.

To set a parameter to NULL, use [sqlite3_bind_null](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).
Alternatively, just don't mention empty parameters in the INSERT statement.

Comment: I edited the code and inserted sqlite3_bind_null. Nothing changes (see the code). The data to be save comes from a server: I can't modify the data, otherwise it will be very complicated to handle all the cases.

Comment: `-1` does not look like a valid parameter number.

Comment: which one u suggest? Anyway reading the doc, I modified the code: putting nil the 3rd parameters is equivalent.

Comment: The parameter number would have been the same `i+1`.